# Marketing Cloud - Individual Privacy and Preferences

Tags: marketing-cloud, preference-center, consent-management

For our new client we are planning to manage the privacy consent on the salesforce object Individual and then sync it to Marketing Cloud via connector.

In MC, Can I create and attribute group to link Contact and Individual?

Can I use the same object to centralize the preference as well? (For instance I want to set the contact purchase preference and not only the privacy consent).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the SFMC part of the question, yes you can synchronize the Individual object since some, rather recent, version of the MC Connect app. This was not always the case, so valid question in my view. It's in Data sources / synchronized like the other SF objects:

[image]

This automatically reproduces the Object / table connections from within SFSC in an attribute group within the BU that the connector is in, typically Parent BU.

So, in that particular BU you do not even need to create the attribute group, it will be created for you.
In other BUs, you can reproduce the object relationship by querying the data into Shared DEs and setting up attribute groups with those, considering the delay that the querying automation that runs hourly at best will entail.

Can you do other things with the individual object? Yes.
Is it a good idea? depends.

You probably won't get a definitive answer here, but there is good official material that is recommended reading, e.g. starting here. Due diligence and applying such information to your particular scenario is something you have to always do yourself:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.icx_b2c_crosscloudengagement_modeling_considerations.htm&type=5

Comment: thanks Jonas, I am going to read it. Please what you think about my second question, the option to host both preference center and unsubscription center in the same web page? Is it a common way to do?

Comment: To be honest, I don't see a question about websites asked in your original post :D  - what data you surface on potentially public websites (websites that dont have a login protection) is exactly what I mean by due diligence you have to go through yourself. For what it's worth, my advice is: surface as little data as possible because you cannot block emails from being forwarded, and then whoever has the link to the preference center has that data. see here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362586/inactivating-a-link-in-the-email-for-ftaf/362598#362598